# Why is this proof for Taylor's Remainder theorem not correct?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am not exactly sure on how to post math equations in the question box so I have all my following information on a google document:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vf20ZyLGQL-K31IjlFkaqCfPaSlszFKtz3mnMVLveC0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please take the time to read about LaTeX/MathJAX in the help pages, and include your problem in the question itself. Links to external resources may become invalid and that would make this thread useless for future readers.

Comment: Your first line assumes that the function is equal to its Taylor series, which is not in general true. (There might be more mistakes, but this one is serious enough to stop right there...)

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the first step seems to be problematic. I'm not fully sure what you're trying to show, but I'll try to give you a hint.
Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is $n+1$ times differentiable and that all derivatives are continuous. Suppose that $c \in [a,b]$. Then we want to show that $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^{k}+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(p)}{(n+1)!}(x-c)^{p+1}$ for some $p$ strictly between $x$ and $c$.

WLOG assume that $x \neq c$

It is clear that there is some $K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^{k}+K(x-c)^{p+1}$.

Then we just have to show that $K=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(p)}{(n+1)!}$ for $p \in (x,c)$.

Consider the following function $g: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(y)}{k!}(x-y)^{k}+K(x-y)^{p+1}$ for all $y \in [a,b]$.

note that both $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ (show it).

Finally, note that $g(c)=f(x)$.

Can you take it from here?

P.S.: One can approach this proof using the mean value theorem, but this is actually a generalization of the mean value theorem for $n=0$, which can easily be verified.